# Nested columns inside tabs Bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this layout:

[image]

Basically, I want to add some nested columns inside those tabs.

What I have tried:

The problem is that the columns inside that specific tabs are overlapping, there is no padding between those.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/hms0qv4z/2/)

Thank you!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="fruits col-md-8">
        <nav>
            <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-content1" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-content1" aria-selected="true">Content 1</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-content2-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-content2" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-content2" aria-selected="false">Content 2</a>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-content1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-content1-tab">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p>asdlaklsdlkasdlksadkldsakldsaklsda</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p>asdlaklsdlkasdlksadkldsakldsaklsda</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p>asdlaklsdlkasdlksadkldsakldsaklsda</p>
                    </div>

                </div>




                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-content2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-content2-tab">...</div>
            </div>
        </div>




    </div>

    <div class="fruits-news col-md-4">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>
```

Comment: Columns do not overlap. Those words are longer than the columns. You need to break the them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns are working as expected. However, the content of the columns (very long words) are not breaking, and therefore overflow the columns. Use:

```
p {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

https://codeply.com/go/5Bi5s4n5DS

Note: The 2nd tab pane is also inside the 1st tab pane in your markup, so the 2nd tab isn't working

Answer (score 0):

There is no margin on columns in Bootstrap, so it's best to work with the padding that they do have. You can put your border on the element that is inside of your columns and you'll see the spacing between them, and from there you can add padding to that inner element (the `p` tags in this case).

Then there is also adding `word-wrap: break-word` if you want your long lines of text to wrap.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col-md-4 p {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="fruits col-md-8">
      <nav>
        <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-content1" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-content1" aria-selected="true">Content 1</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-content2-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-content2" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-content2" aria-selected="false">Content 2</a>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-content1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-content1-tab">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <p>asdlaklsdlkasdlksadkldsakldsaklsda</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <p>asdlaklsdlkasdlksadkldsakldsaklsda</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <p>asdlaklsdlkasdlksadkldsakldsaklsda</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-content2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-content2-tab">...</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fruits-news col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score -1):

In bootstrap4 you dont need to set class as `col-md-(number)`, just `col-md`

Just replace that:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>asdlaklsdlkasdlksadkldsakldsaklsda</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>asdlaklsdlkasdlksadkldsakldsaklsda</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>asdlaklsdlkasdlksadkldsakldsaklsda</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

By

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            One of three columns
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ao1kn5rj/)